# Aumentar el timeout a las requests que recibes en tu API

Tags: javascript, api, express, swagger

Tengo una API desarrollada en Swagger y basada en Express. El timeout de Express por default es de 30000 (30s), pero necesito aumentarlo a 120000 (120s) debido a que una de las funciones de la API tiene que realizar otra petición a un servicio externo que tarda de media 40-50 segundos en responder.
El código del servidor:

```
SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  // install middleware
  app.use(timeout(120000));
  app.use(haltOnTimedout);
  
  swaggerExpress.register(app)

  function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
    if (!req.timedout) next();
  }


  var port = process.env.PORT || 10011;
  app.listen(port);
  //console.log(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths)
});
```

Aquí os adjunto también el código de error que nos aparece en la consola. Hemos intentado varias soluciones pero no consigo arreglarlo:

```
Mar 14 12:21:41 appname.com heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/example" host=appname.com fwd="11.111.11.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

El problema lo vemos en que el servicio ha tardado 30 segundos.
La función se sigue ejecutando por detrás ya que es asíncrona, pero la respuesta a la petición es 503.

Comment: Creo que no debeŕias pasar el middleware justo cuando se inicializa Swagger. Sino más bien crear una lógica de tipo `app.use(process.env.isSwagger ?   timeout(120000)
: null );`.  Aparte de eso el timeout que te está saliendo puede que sea de lado de *heroku* y no de express.

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza Si, de hecho el error es de Heroku. Pero en su blog tienen este post: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preventing-h12-errors-request-timeouts en el que te explica como evitar los errores H12. Mi servidor es nodejs por lo que según ese post sería esta la solución: https://github.com/expressjs/timeout que es lo que estoy intentando.